# Initialize vector<Point2i> inside a struct

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to initialize a certain space for the vector inside a struct(says n blocks) using c++. But inside a struct, one can't use the vector initializer directly, thus I tried to define the type outside the struct and call the constructor function outside but within the struct. Like the following:

```
typedef vector <Point2i> fourNearestPoints;  
struct nearestFourPointsAndWeighting{  
.  
.  
.
fourNearestPoints nearestpoints;
nearestFourPointsAndWeighting() : nearestPoints(4, (0,0) ) {}

};
```

However, an error of "member function already defined or declared" occurred. 
I believe may be I called the function wrongly or simply my syntax is wrong, thus lead to redefinition of member function. SO what is the correct way to initialize vector inside a struct?

Comment: search for initializer list

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: "_..keep on producing error_" And the error is...????

Comment: The initialization of your vector (`nearestPoints`) has `(0,0)` as the default value, but this should be of type `Point2i`, probably `Point2i(0,0)`.

Comment: If you're trying to use C++11 initializer syntax there, it should be `nearestPoints(4, {0, 0})` (curly braces instead of parens).

Comment: @DarioOO
Do you mean I can use initializer list to do the job instead of the way I used here?

Comment: @Roddy
The error I get is :"member function already defined or declared"at the line I tried to initalize the vector.

Comment: @NathanOliver
I will edit my question later today. I know this is for the better representation of the problem.

Comment: @yati sagade
I do try but the same error occurs.

Comment: @Carl yes. I mean that